# Twitter Login Integration in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, xcode6

I am using Twitter to log in to my app. I am using `TWTRLoginButton`. It has been added successfully to my view. When I am click the button, it doesn't navigate to next login page.

Comment: check if you have added navigationController or not

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: my twitter login button is added, but it doesn't navigate to login page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this URL step by step...

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/configure

And use this demo..

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter

Comment: Thank u Rahul, can i use this STTWitter project for integration?

Comment: - (IBAction)twitterAction:(id)sender {
    TWTRLogInButton *logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    }];
     logInButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:logInButton];
      }